# How to export the image in a HttpRequestMessage

Tags: .net, rest

I'd like to develop a Web API, that downloads an image in a httpresponsemessage as result. But my code returns the image, without exporting it as attachement.

In the past implementation, the commented code is used to export the image. But it doesn't exist anymore...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might help - http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/everything-you-want-to-know-about-asp-net-web-api-content-negotation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set content-disposition header to your response object

```
response.ContentType = "image/png";
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=File.png");
```

Update#1
Add the headers to the client as shown below, instead of adding it to the response

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpg"));
```

Comment: Maybe it's  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg"); response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "abc.jpg"
                };